# Parameter sniffing = On with Parameterization = forced. Which takes precedence?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, parameter-sniffing

These two settings seem to contradict each other. One forces plan parameterization so that only one plan gets created. The other allows for multiple plans

If you have Parameterization = forced, should parameter sniffing be false, or does one take precedence?

**Additional details**

Regarding the comments below, parameter sniffing is a [database scoped option](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4286/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing-as-a-database-scoped-configuration/) as of SS 2016. (was a surprise to me too).  See also: [SQLShack: SQL Server 2016 Parameter Sniffing](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/)

Comment: Could you post what setting name the parameter sniffing one is you're referring to? I'm not aware of such a setting.

Comment: @George.Palacios I have edited the question to include a link which outlines this option

Comment: @Zane  see the edit above. Should have included links in the post

Comment: Well... Looks like it's time to try and build a test and learn something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These do not conflict. Parameter sniffing is the process that uses the parameter values when building a plan. Forced parameterization turns literals into parameters in queries.

So having both on will turn literals into parameters, but not use those values when estimating cardinality.

[More on parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

[More on forced parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175037(v=sql.105))

Answer (score 3):

Parameterization and sniffing are separate activities. An ad-hoc statement can be parameterized by SQL Server without parameter values being sniffed.

Paul White has an excellent blog post on : [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) which covers both Parameter Sniffing and parameterization in detail with examples.